# Installing sqoop, give bin/sqoop-list-databases: line 26: /Users/apple/sqoop: is a directory

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

When I install sqoop it gives me this error.

> sqoop git:(derektest) ✗ bin/sqoop-list-databases –connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/ --username root -p
>   readlink: illegal option -- f
>   usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
>   usage: dirname path
>   bin/sqoop-list-databases: line 26: /Users/apple/sqoop: is a directory
>   bin/sqoop-list-databases: line 26: exec: /Users/apple/sqoop: cannot execute:
> Undefined error: 0

Really hope someone could help me with this. This is killing me now.

Comment: can you format you command and console output and error properly. Its not readable. Also are you trying to install sqoop with this command or validating installation by listing databases?

Comment: i install the sqoop with brew. I try to figure out if it has been installed well.

Comment: ➜  1.4.5 git:(master) bin/sqoop-help          
readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
usage: dirname path
/usr/local/Cellar/sqoop/1.4.5/libexec/bin/sqoop-help: line 26: /Users/apple/sqoop: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Cellar/sqoop/1.4.5/libexec/bin/sqoop-help: line 26: exec: /Users/apple/sqoop: cannot execute: No such file or directory

Comment: This is the command i typed. And it gives me this error. But the problem is there is no "/users/apple/sqoop" directory.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of "readlink" which is installed as coreutils in MacOS.

use **greadlink** (installed as part of **brew install coreutils**)

for example, for the file = **bin/sqoop-list-databases** on line number 26 replace readlink with greadlink like following

```
prgm=`greadlink -f $0`
bin=`dirname ${prgm}`
bin=`cd ${bin} && pwd`
...
```